# BB10 simulator is showing up side down

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I don't know why I am getting my BB10 simulator up side down while running in VMWare player.Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As written [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/simulator/simulator_gestures.html), you have to tap the bottom right corner of the screen to change the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, BB10 Simulator showed up side down.  If you look at your monitor in mirror reflect, you will see the fine result in the mirror LOL.  This outcome looks like HUD (Head up display).

I ran BB10 Sim on VMware-Workstation 5.5 and 6.5.
The VMware-Wrkstn seems embedded VMware-Player. Unfortunately, it doesn't compatible with BB10 Sim.

Found three solutions

1. Uninstall VMWare-Wrkstn 5.5 (or 6.5) and install Standalone VMware Player 5 (VMware Player for Windows 32-bit and 64-bit) which downloaded from  https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0
2. I have tested VMWare-Wrkstn 9 (trial license 30 days), BB10 SIM works fine.
3. Since I didn't have register license for version 9.
   I still need to use VMWare-Wrkstn 6.5, so my workaround is to install and run
   (BB10 SIM)and(VMWare Player 5) within VMware-Wrkstn 6.5.

   - VM device processors Execution Mode must be us 'Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI'
   - Your host machine must be support EPT (Core i ++)
   - My host machine Core 2 Duo, didn't support this scenario. So it failed.

* I finally found that, I should have at least VMware Workstation 7 which bundled VMware Player 3, to run BB10 Simulator ***